# Why are errors named as "Exception" but not as "Error" in programming languages?

Tags: programming-languages, terminology, exceptions

I've been thinking about that for quite a while actually. I am not a native English speaker myself but still, I have years of programming experience and I always asked myself this. Why is it named as `Exception` but not `Error` since they are errors?

It could be `PageNotFoundError` instead of `PageNotFoundException`!

Comment: Not all exceptional situations are errors.

Comment: It's the difference between swerving the car and crashing the car.

Comment: Are you just talking about the naming of the specific exception classes? Then note that in some ecosystems, those *are* called `XYError` -- for instance, in Python.

Comment: Mind you, Java does have an Error class, which inherits from Throwable. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html for more details. You may also like to check the "Direct Known Subclasses" category.

Comment: I would like to say that this conundrum has nothing to do with English. It's more a logical categorization in whichever spoken language in which you choose to be proficient.

Comment: "Why does it call it an exception if it happens every time I run the program?"

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**They don't need to be errors at all.  The fact that the page is not there may be just an interesting fact rather than an actual error.**  They seem to get used as errors almost all the time, I admit.  But sometimes they're used to break out of loops, or let you know that a string is not a valid number.  They can be used to hold and return vast amounts of useful data--as part of a fairly normal return.  (Some languages are a bit slow with their exceptions, in that case throwing them frequently is a bad idea.)  In theory anyway, an exception merely means "don't do a normal return, go up the call stack until you find someone interested in this."

Even a null pointer exception might not mean much to you.  You call someone else's code, and then catch a null pointer exception because you know it's apt to blow up, print a message saying whose fault it is, and carry on and get your job done.

Comment: Although the use of exception mechanisms as control flow can be confusing and I think is generally frowned upon.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Depends on the language/culture.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: they're awkward, with the try/catch/finally blocks, and they can be slow if you are not careful (or even if you are). But they can be handy (on very rare occasions) to jump many levels of method calls; for instance, when an elaborate search has found what it was looking for halfway through.  Also, Java doesn't let you return values in parameters (unlike C#, for instance), so there, if you normally return true/false, an exception can let you return an elaborate object instead.  Again, this would be pretty rare.

Comment: @RalphChapin: I guess in Java you would typically return an object including the "true/false" value *and* further information instead of throwing an exception. And I would not recommend to use an exception to present the result of an "elaborate search". An exception  is fine when the search fails, for example, because the data or file where your search applies is erroneous. Of course, that's somewhat a question of personal preference.

Comment: @DocBrown: I once wrote a sudoku solver that does recursive search that backtracks when it fails to find the solution in the current attempt and retry with a different value; and when a solution is found, it throws an exception containing the solution. The issue here failure is the "normal" situation, and success is an "exceptional" situation; and since there are multiple points in the solver where it calls itself, without using exception you'd have to write lots of boilerplates for checking whether a call is returning from a successful search or from a failed search.

Comment: @DocBrown: exception can be used as a pure control structure, without implying that the situation is erroneous. Breaking out from a deep recursion is one situation where the other possible solutions would be extremely ugly compared to just throwing an exception.

Comment: @Lie Ryan: ugly? Like setting a private member in a class? You consider that ugly? Or just like returning a little structure instead of a simple value? You consider that ugly, too? I consider the break out via exception as much uglier. I also dislike your sudoko solver example because it's just a dirty hack and I bet you could've written that cleaner and simpler.

Comment: @Falcon: yes you could just return a 'finished' value, that just means every time you recurse, you're going to have to do: `for (...) { if (func() == finished) { return finished; } else { itfailedsocheckanother(); }}` but considering that there are multiple points in the code where it is func() is recursing, the exception-less solution gets uglier every time you add more recursion. **That** is what I call a cargo-cult programming, it is essentially simulating exceptions in a language that already have one because cult leader says "thy shall not use exceptions".

Comment: @Falcon: By using exception, you can just assume that if func() returns, then it must be because there is no solution on that search path (i.e. a failure), so the code simplifies to: `for(...) { func(); itfailedsocheckanother() }`. I choose the exception ways after evaluating many other exception-less ways, all the other ways adds a burden on the calling point to check the return value; while the cleanest and simplest is the one with exception, so no, I don't think you can write it cleaner any other way.

Comment: @Lie Ryan: Well, I think you could design that algorithm differently, but I have a different philosophy. I don't think that the exception is clean at all, I think it is being abused as some sort of Goto. It also depends on the language. Java forces you to handle the exception but it's definitely a WTF (the only measurement of code quality tm) to have a function that returns an exception upon success. BTW: Cargo Cult programming is something completely different.

Comment: @Falcon: Ah... the stock "it looks like Goto" argument, that arguments works for saying you shouldn't use loops or if statements or function calls, because "they all looks like gotos". Returning success with exception is only a WTF if you're associating exception with errors. For me, when used in this way, a try-catch block is like "a promise to return here after a long journey", the behavior of the try-except+throw is pretty similar to function-calls+returns except it's for a much longer journeys which may involve a very deep call stack when you finished the quest for solution.

Comment: I'd add that even Exceptions are distinct from programming errors - while 1/0 will throw an DivdeByZeroException, at compile time, that's a programming error; but at runtime, that could be a user-input error, or an environment setting error, depending on where the values for the dividing values came from. It's exceptional for the division operator to try and perform that, but the error that caused the exception may not have been there.

Answer (score 21):

The mechanism of exceptions is not *always* used to signal errors. Exceptions are thrown in out of the ordinary situations that require a separate code path to process, including errors. For example, a user providing a name of a file that does not exist, or entering a letter instead of a digit in a numeric field, are exceptional situations requiring special handling, but these are not errors.

In some programming environments, such as Java, special [`Error`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) objects are provided to report "true errors", situations that a reasonable application should not attempt to handle. These objects are delivered using the same mechanism that is used for delivering exceptions, but they have a special meaning of signals of unrecoverable situations.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have an etymological research about the origins of that, but I can understand that using the term "Error" may not be precise in all situations; also as almostSharepointMaster mentioned, it is better to think of the error and the exception thrown as separated entities.

When you're in a high-level programing language, it makes sense to assume that an exception is always caused by an error, although I agree also with dasblinkenlight that even then an exception not always is the consequence of an error. I, for instance, use exceptions to terminate threads collaboratively.

The first time I saw the term "exception" was in the 80386 Assembly manual. I remember that when I saw it looked instantly natural to me. To call that an error would not be correct, because there are no errors in Assembly; there are simply conditions the processor can't deal with (if that's an error - from the programmer, the user or the system - well, the processor is completely agnostic to that). I don't know if Intel really originated the term or not, but maybe...

Answer (score 3):

Commonly Exception is used to name an event which is not correct but can be recovered from, like an `out_of_range` exception in C++, which is thrown when accessing an element in a vector or array that doesn't exist. Clearly such an event is not correct, but it happening shouldn't mean your whole program crashes.

On the other hand errors are usually used to name something that should crash everything, something like a stack overflow is an example of an event that should terminate the program as the program can't handle it internally. In other words: an error is major, while an exception is comparatively minor.

Answer (score 3):

I think this has more to do with "evolution" of error handling. With C/C++ (before exception handling was added) languages, if a function failed, the only way to tell was through the return value (e.g. `HRESULT` in win32). So typically you ended up catching exit codes of each function call and do a check. This approach makes code messier. And lot of times developers will just avoid adding these checks out of laziness.

With the introduction of exception handling, developers now had **two options** to raise an  error. So the "exception" word was used to distinguish errors from "exit status" errors. After a period of time, exception handling has become a popular way to propagate errors because code is much easier to read, maintain and there can be a single place where you can have error handling logic.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, they are named as ABCError
Eg: KeyError, IndexError

http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html

So I think it depends on language that you use.

Comment: Don't forget VB (classic, not. Net). On Error Goto was used. And the most amazing invention of all time "On Error Resume Next"

Comment: In Python, errors are a subset of exceptions. There are four standard exceptions that inherit from Exception but don't inherit from StandardError:  StopIteration, GeneratorExit, KeyboardInterrupt and SystemExit.

Answer (score 1):

When an error occurs, either the system or the currently executing application reports it by throwing an exception containing information about the error. Once thrown, an exception is handled by the application or by the default exception handler.

An error thows an exception that details the error, so not everything is an error that is an exception if that makes sense ;), for instance an noneimplemetedexception shouldnt be an error but thows an exception.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions and errors are different.

Exceptions are situations a program can overcome, like say you try to open a file and it doesn't exist, while errors are situations a program can't do nothing about, like a disk failure or a RAM failure.

Comment: Huh? I’d say it’s totally the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS/Mac programming, we have both Exceptions and Errors in a single language.

At least in that environment an exception is "non-recoverable", while an error is "recoverable".

For example:

- if you have an array with 10 items, and you try to access the item at index 30 - that will be an exception. You made a mistake in your programming.
- if you try to download a URL but there is no internet connection, that is to be expected and you should present some kind of message to the user.

Exceptions typically crash your app, while errors typically return `nil` and an error object (returned as a by reference method parameter). You can catch exceptions with a try/catch/finally block but it's recommended never to use this language feature - if it is possible to recover from an exception in any way, then you shouldn't be throwing an exception at all (you should return an error object instead).

Comment: Well, it is entirely different than what Exception and Errors are meant to the other developers then!

Comment: Every language is different I guess. Objective-C/Cocoa is one of the oldest languages in active use (from around 1983), so perhaps it's a bit old fashioned. Still, if the definition changes from one community to another it's important to know that.

Comment: 10 years later: Since Objective-C’s error handling has been moved into Swift and looks quite similar to exceptions while Objective-C exceptions have gone in Swift it doesn’t seem to have anything to do with “old-fashioned”.

Answer (score 0):

An **error** is something that has gone wrong in the execution of the program. Often this is dealt with by raising an **exception**, but

- there is nothing that forces a programmer to handle an error by raising an exception, and
- there is nothing that forces a programmer to raise exceptions only in the case of an error.

Error is a *semantic* concept: it is applied by the programmer or user, who comes to the program with expectations, to describe the difference between their expectations and reality. Only a person can say whether a routine is in an error state or not.

An exception is a *syntactic* concept: it is something in the program itself, independent of anyone's expectations about what that program is supposed to do. A routine either does or does not raise an exception, regardless of what anyone thinks.

Answer (score 0):

Raising and handling exceptions are control flow features and the name of the exception should follow the intented usage. The designer of code and API should find good and consistent naming schemes.

So the answer to your question is: it depends on the context and perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions evolved as a generalization of errors. The [first programming language to include an exception mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#History) was Lisp in the early 1970s. There's a good summary in [*A Pattern of Language Evolution* by Gabriel and Steele](http://www.dreamsongs.com/Files/PatternOfLanguageEvolution.pdf). Exceptions (which were not yet called exceptions) arose from the need to specify the behavior of a program if an error occurs. One possibility is to halt the program, but this is not always helpful. Lisp implementations traditionally have had a way to enter the debugger on an error, but sometimes programmers wanted to include error handling in their program. So 1960s Lisp implementations had a way to say “do this, and if an error occurs then do that instead”. Originally errors came from primitive functions, but programmers found it convenient to deliberately trigger an error in order to skip some part of the program and jump to the error handler.

In 1972, the modern form of exception handling in Lisp appeared in MacLisp: `throw` and `catch`. The [Software Preservation Group](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP/maclisp_family/) lists a lot of material on early Lisp implementations, including [The MACLISP Reference Manual Revision 0 by David Moon](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP/MIT/Moon-MACLISP_Reference_Manual-Apr_08_1974.pdf). The primitives `catch` and `throw` are documented in §5.3 p.43.

> `catch` is the LISP function for doing structured non-local exits. `(catch x)` evaluates `x` and returns its values, except that if during the evaluation of `x` `(throw y)` should be evaluated, `catch` immediately returns `y` without further evaluating `x`.
>
> `catch` may also be used with a econd argument, not evaluated, which is used as a tag to distinguish between nested catches. (…)
>
> `throw` is used with `catch` as a structured nonlocal exit mechanism.
>
> `(throw x)` evaluates `x` and throws the value back to the most recent `catch`.
>
> `(throw x <tag>)` throws the value of `x` back to the most recent `catch` labelled with `<tag>` or unlabelled.

The focus is on *nonlocal* control flow. It's a form of goto (an upward-only goto), which is also called a *jump*. The metaphor is that one part of the program *throws* the value to return to the exception handler, and the exception handler *catches* that value and returns it.

Most programming languages today pack the tag and the value in an exception object, and combine the catching mechanism with a handling mechanism.

Exceptions are not necessarily errors. They're a way to exit from a block of code and from the surrounding blocks, escaping until a handler for the exception is reached. Whether such a thing is considered an ”error“ in the intuitive sense is subjective.

Some languages make a distinction between the terms “error” and “exception”. For example, some Lisp dialects have both `throw` to raise an exception (control flow for users, meant to perform a non-local exit in a way that doesn't indicate that anything went “wrong”) and `signal` to raise an error (which indicates that something went “wrong” and may trigger a debug event).

Answer (score -1):

You will find it differntly interpreted in different programming language implementations. As dasblinkenlight said that's a java point of view of having a demarcation between Error and Exception. In many programming languages exceptions are violations which can be handled or allowed to be bubbled up to pass on to the highest possible code module.
Errors generally are situations where your language's runtime container handles (and many cases just halt the execution).

Answer (score -1):

An error is always an error. An exception is an error in the current context. That is, an exception is context sensitive. An example of an exception would be adding an ascii "a" to an integer "1". An error might be something like using an undefined operator like "+!" in most languages.

Some languges will allow you to Define your way out of the situation if that is really what you want to do.